# How do I permanently set an environment variable for a specific Flatpak application?

Tags: linux, configuration, environment-variables, flatpak

I would like to set an environment variable so that it is set when I launch a specific Flatpak application, and only set for this application. How do I go about doing this in a permanent manner?

Comment: And how can I do it non-persistently, actually? Do the usual shell commands of prepending the env variable before the command work?

Comment: Oh I saw `-env=VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE` also works with `flatpak run`. :)

Comment: @rugk I think it's actually `--env` not `-env`

Comment: @robertspierre Oh yes, of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this via the `flatpak override` command.

To set only one environment variable you can use this syntax:

```
flatpak override --env=VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE full.application.Name
```

To set multiple environment variables you can use this syntax:

```
flatpak override --env=VARIABLE_NAME_ONE=VARIABLE_VALUE_ONE --env=VARIABLE_NAME_TWO=VARIABLE_VALUE_TWO full.application.Name
```

This will set it globally and therefore requires you to run the command as root. If you want to do this for your current user, you can add the `--user` parameter to the command, like so:

```
flatpak override --user --env=VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE full.application.Name
```

Source and further reading: http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-override

Comment: (1) I don’t have Flatpak, so I can’t experiment, but are you sure the `--env="NAME1=VALUE1 NAME2=VAL2"` syntax really works?  I see nothing in the documentation that suggests that it does.  Rather, it suggests `--env="NAME1=VALUE1"` `--env="NAME2=VAL2"`.  (2) If it works as you describe, I don’t see how you would set an environment variable value that contains space(s) and equal sign(s).  For example, I wonder what ``--env="RELATIVITY=Einstein says E=mc^2"`` does.

Comment: as @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' mentioned `--env` can be used multiple times and join them with space is not working.

Comment: I thought I tested it and saw it work, but maybe I'm wrong. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [Flatseal application](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) lets you set environment variables and other things relating to your installed flatpaks in a convenient fashion if you are GUI sort of person.

Comment: This answer could be improved by describing (and showing) *how* this answers the question.